# How to change the properties of a UI control within a grid once the row and column is known

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I am having trouble accessing a UI control (in my case: labels and Rectangles) arranged within a grid. I need to access this control at a specific location in the grid (given the row and column no.) and need to change its background color, font-size etc.

The code I am using so far looks like this:

```
foreach (UIElement ui in myGrid.Children)
{
     int rowIndex = System.Windows.Controls.Grid.GetRow(ui);
     int colIndex = System.Windows.Controls.Grid.GetColumn(ui);
     if (rowIndex == TargetRow && colIndex == TargetCol)
           //change the background property of the ui control to yellow
}
```

The If statement is where I am stumped (assuming the remainder code is correct too). How do I use the properties of this UIELement 'ui'. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either set `Control.Background` for the Labels or `Shape.Fill` for the Rectangles:

```
if (rowIndex == TargetRow && colIndex == TargetCol)
{
    if (ui is Control)
    {
        ((Control)ui).Background = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
    else if (ui is Shape)
    {
        ((Shape)ui).Fill = Brushes.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Instead of explicitly looping over all child elements, you may use LINQ to find the matching UIElement like this:

```
using System.Linq;
...

var ui = myGrid.Children.Cast<UIElement>().FirstOrDefault(
    c => Grid.GetColumn(c) == TargetCol && Grid.GetRow(c) == TargetRow);

if (ui is Control)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to cast the element to the appropriate type.  You might want to try casting to the lowest element in the class hierarchy that contains the property you're looking for -- for `Background`, this would be [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.Control_properties(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (rowIndex == TargetRow && colIndex == TargetCol)
{ 
    //change the background property of the ui control to yellow
    if (ui is Control)
        ((Control)ui).Background = Brushes.Yellow;
}
```

You could also use a Linq-style iterator:

```
foreach (var control in myGrid.Children.OfType<Control>()
    .Where(child => Grid.GetRow(child) == TargetRow && Grid.GetColumn(child) == TargetCol)
{
    control.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
}
```